# How to fix folds in sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am applying CV in several prediction tasks and would like to use the same folds all the time for each of my parameter sets - and if possible also in different python scripts, since the performance really depends on the folds.
I am working with sklearns KFold:

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=False, random_state=1986)
```

and build my folds by

```
for idx_split, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X, Y)):
    X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]
```

and loop over them like

```
for idx_alpha, alpha in enumerate([0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]):
    # [...]
    for idx_split, (train_index, test_index) in enumerate(kf.split(X, Y)):
        X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
        y_train, y_test = Y[train_index], Y[test_index]**
```

Although I choose a random_state and set a numpy seed the folds are not equal all the time. What can I do to make this happen and possibly share my folds via several python scripts?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be reinventing the [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) ;-)

Try this approach:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25)

param_grid = dict(model__alpha=[0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1])

model = Lasso()  # put here algorithm, that you want to use

folds = 3
# alternatively you can prepare folds yourself
#folds = KFold(n_splits=folds, shuffle=False, random_state=1986)
grid_search = GridSearchCV(model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=folds, n_jobs=-1, verbose=2)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_pred = grid_search.best_estimator_.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Thanks! Does GridSearchCV always provides the same splits over all parameter combinations?

Comment: Do you have any idea to provide the same splits in different python scripts?

Comment: @N8_Coder, can you explain bit more? Why do you want to use it in different scripts?

Comment: The model's performance depends highly on the data in my splits. Hence, I want to use the same splits everywhere.

Comment: @N8_Coder, well, you didn't explain why you can't use them in the same script (why do you need multiple scripts)... But, anyway, you may want to try to save your splits as a list or a dictionary and persists it to disk using `sklearn.externals.joblib`...